# Recreating ChatR fails. SignalR won't start hub

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to get a hold on SignalR and dove right into [ChatR](https://github.com/vgheri/ChatR/tree/master/ChatR)

I started out by creating an mvc3 application and writing down my own implementation, keeping the basic functionality of the code from the git. It didn't work out, so I revoked my own changes and ended up with an 1:1 copy of ChatR without any of my enhancements - still didn't work. 
So I copy/pasted the source code into my project and it still won't fire up.

Chrome gives me the following 2 javascript errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'hubConnection' hubs:154
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined localhost:174
```

I've read, that Jquery might be referenced twice in the code. First before SignalR.js is referenced and once after SignalR, nullifying the object, which isn't the case.

I then downloaded KsigDo, to see if I can recreate the problem on an completly unrelated project. The above mentioned error pops up again.

The bottom line is: ChatR source code downloaded - works. ChatR copy in my own namespace doesn't

I've tried this in vs2010 professional/vs2012 web with mvc3 and 4.

I hope you fine folks can help me out.
Kind regards.

Comment: If you can provide a link to your source i'll take a look.  There's a million things that could be causing this issue.  The demo works fine for me.

Comment: I left my machine at the office over the weekend. I'll wrap the source up on monday and host it somewhere, propably at github.

Comment: If I just knew how to work with gitHub ... stupid me.